# breakpoint-sass Install Issue

Tags: ruby, sass, breakpoint-sass

I am trying to run breakpoint and I have followed the steps:

1. using command line: `gem install Breakpoint`
2. Updated Config.rb: `require 'breakpoint'`
3. on scss file I have included: `@import "breakpoint";`

However, when I use compass watch I get the error:

> Gem:LoadError on line ["2007"] of C: Unable to activate
>   breakpoint-2.4.2, because sass-3.2.19 conflicts with sass <~> 3.3.0

running `sass -v` I can see that I have version 3.3.8 of sass installed.

Can anyone help? Happy to provide more info if needed!

Comment: possible duplicate of [conflicting sass / compass versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20999196/conflicting-sass-compass-versions)

Answer (score 4):

Install the latest alpha version of compass:

```
gem install compass --pre
```

Answer (score 0):

The [installation instructions](https://github.com/Team-Sass/breakpoint/wiki/Installation) for Breakpoint recommend you use [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) to install Breakpoint instead of a straight `gem install` in order to ensure all of your dependencies are in check. This is a general best practice when working with anything Ruby related, not just Breakpoint.

Comment: I did this and I still had issues. I have also tried the answer and it now complains about a circular reference along with the the original problem